# How to set combo box text and value fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, excel

How to set combo box text field and value field in Excel VBA, like we set for dropdown list in web applications, For example,

```
DropdownList.DataTextField ="EmpName";
DropdownList.DataValueField = "EmpCode";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With ComboBox1 
   .AddItem "Item1" 
   .AddItem "Item2"
End With
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

Comment: mehow, above statement will set same value for text and value property of combo box. i.e. combobox.Text and combobox.Value will return "Item1". What  I required is that,  combobox.Text should return "Item1" and combobox.Value should return 1. so how do bind these values to combobox.

Comment: why would you want the .Value to return 1? What is it that you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

When I've created an Excel ComboBox from Access VBA, I've used the following sytnax:

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
    With .Object
        .TextAlign = 2
        '.LinkedCell = "D6"
        '.ListFillRange = "G16:G23"
    End With
End With
```

But in Excel the two commented lines don't seem to work. Hope that helps?